# Deploying Strapi to Heroku

Tags: heroku, deployment, content-management-system, strapi

I've been following the official Strapi tutorials on how to develop and deploy an application to Heroku and it seems you have to configure some files like ./config/environments/**/database.json.

The problem is that, installing the app without --quickstart (yarn create strapi-app my-project), my config folder just has a **functions** folder and **database.js** and **server.js** files.

Should I create manually this **database.json** or is this supposed to be created automatically when initializing the app without --quickstart?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was also confused so I manually created the folders /environments/production and inside the file database.json and it worked for me.

Link to the docs: https://strapi.io/documentation/3.0.0-beta.x/deployment/heroku.html#_4-update-your-database-config-file

Comment: I did the same and I could deploy the app to Heroku. Thank you!